# Sync local repository with remote repository

Tags: github, repository, tortoisegit

I'm new to Github, so far I already know how to clone, commit and make pull requests. However, I'm stuck on something:

I have forked a repository and committed to the local repository. In the mean time, the project that I forked was updated so now my local repository is outdated. How do I overwrite all changes I made and make it so that my local repository is an exact copy of the one I forked?

I'm using TortoiseGit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can hard reset your repo with main repo using

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: How do you do that with TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to loose your local changes simply delete the local repository and do a **git clone** otherwise you should do a **git pull** which merges all the changes from the remote repository into your local one.

*Update*
The best thing is to make local changes into a local branch which can be created by using:

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

Afterwards you can make changes on that branch and update the repository simply by doing a

```
git pull
```

but first got to master before it (git checkout master).
With this it's not necessary to clone the repository several time. I wasn't sure if you had used a local branch.

Comment: Is there no simpler way than having to delete everything, clone everything, build with maven, import into Eclipse and configure project-specific settings every single time the repo is updated?

Comment: After doing what you said, only the repo on my computer is up to date, the one on Github is still outdated.. So do I have delete the project and refork it too?

There has to be a simpler way right........